# Should I build my server with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, server

I want to build a server that will listen to a custom port and talk with my web application through a custom protocol. The server will have a dispatcher and workers that will undertake a task and complete it.

Is Laravel up for the job or should I go with something more specific ?

EDIT: 
I would like to clarify that it's not an API. Basically a php script will run on loop in CLI mode (meaning no Apache or NGINX involved here). The script will open a socket and listen on a certain port for connections from clients. Once a client connects, the server will start some jobs and send the answer. It also involves a job queue to which the server will connect(probably a database), get the jobs and fork new processes that will complete the jobs.

Comment: Why don't you simply use a standard "off-the-shelf" job queuing system ike Gearman or RabbitMQ?

Comment: Because the demo project we did was made in Laravel, there are a bunch of logic in there, so if Laravel is a good option, would save us a lot of time.

Comment: your question lacks some clarifications. No sure anyone understands what you want to accomplish

Comment: @Matt Baker: Gearman looks like a very good candidate for what I want, my question is if Laravel is also a good candidate if I build the job queuing system myself with it.
I'm asking because in the past I had issues with memory leaks inside PHP scripts so I'm wondering if someone built something of the sort with Laravel and didn't have any issues like the one I just mentioned.

Comment: Laravel is not a good candidate, because you'll have to write your job queue management/processing completely from scratch.... or use the built-in Queue options that are all based around existing purpose-built third-party queue management tools like Gearman and RabbitMQ.... why spend your time adding an extra layer of homebrew complexity around something that already exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

It seems that you don't need much of a framework at all (except maybe for the database operations part. since you if you use sockets you will (probably) not use much of the framework's functionality like routing, view templating...) Depending on the complexity of your database I'd use a framework or not. If it's very complex, features like Eloqent might help... I think you should think on how much of the framework you will use and if you can only take the stuff you need trough Composer instead.

END EDIT

Should you use Laravel/PHP to build a server - it will be probably too slow for that purpose.

1) If you want to make your own server (not website or API) I'd much rather go for Node.js or something along those lines (ruby, python, C#..)

2) By "custom protocol" I assume you don't mean something different than HTTP/ TCP/IP ? Then what do you mean by a "custom protocol" ?

Comment: Ah sorry, should I have made it more clear, it's TCP of course but I was referring on how the communication will work (eg XML, JSON, how they greet, etc)

Comment: Why do you say it's slower? since a server will run in loop, the process that makes PHP slower (interpretation) is left only at server boot. Am I wrong ?

Comment: If your communication will work with something like XML/JSON then you're building an API prbably?! Then PHP / Laravel might be perfectly okay. However L might be an overkill. Might want to try something like [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/) or [Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/) ... What is it you're trying to build in the end?

I am saying PHP is slow because, well, it is. It runs trough Apache/Nginx server and it's best for serving HTTP requests (but not socket/websocket/long polling, those will pretty much kill your server...)

Comment: It's not an API. I've added some clarifications to my first post, hope this clears what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Editing my answer...

Comment: Thanks, yes, I wouldn't need all the framework, only parts of it.